# Tooltip formatter for multiple axes in Highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart with 2 Y axes, one plotting some values in milliseconds that need to be converted into a prettier representation and another that just plots a value that does not need any formatting.

I've used a formatter on the first axis that does what I need the problem is that it is applied to both axes. Is there a way to have a tooltip formatter for each axis?

The only way I could find is to use a shared tooltip but I'd rather have them separate.

Can anybody think of a better way? Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers

Luis

Answer (score 2):

Long time since this was asked but I ran into the same problem. You can define a tooltip in each series map. That way it lets you format each individually.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean by 'shared tooltip', but in the formatter function you can use this.series.index to differentiate between each series.

If the series has a type you can also use this.series.options.type.

Comment: Hello thanks for your help. By shared I meant the shared property of the tooltip. I have got it working using:
'if (this.series.index == 1)'